# Workaround for Access Error 3047

Tags: ms-access

I'm getting error 3047 in MS Access 2007 importing a large amount of data (beware of users with free text fields).  I found online that this is due to the 2Kb limit on records in access.  Is there a way around this limit without normalizing the table (and re-writing all the code)?

Answer (score 3):

Memo fields and OLE fields are not counted as part of the record limits.

Comment: @Remou, the problem is not the *field* size, but the record *size*.

Comment: I understand that, however, data stored in a memo field does not count as part of the record size limit, therefore, the text field can be changed to a memo field as a workaround for your problem `memo: 65,535 when entering data through the user interface;
1 gigabyte of character storage when entering data programmatically`   OLE Fields are also excluded.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoide re-writing much code, while still normalizing.

In that case, normalize the tables, and then create a query that 'de-normalizes' it back into what the original table looked like (same name, same fields).  That way, anything that depends on the currently de-normized table will be able to refer to the new query without having to be re-coded.

Comment: Can you insert into an access query (like you can with some views)?

Comment: My idea was basically just indended for a bandaid (with SELECTS in mind, not INSERTS so much).  The fact of the matter is, there is more you can do with a band-aid approach, but in the end, there is no good permanent substitute for normalized tables in terms of scalability, and the more band-aids you use, the worse things eventually will get.

If it's not too much re-coding, then I'd suggest at this point creating INSERT/UPDATE procedures for your newly normalized tables.  (i.e., sub-forms, or whatever you decide to use)